# Cannot run grails console

Tags: grails

Upgraded to Grails 2.3.2 and trying 'grails console' will get me the below error.
Any idea what went wrong with the latest upgrade?

```
| Error Fatal error during compilation java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method setTargetDirectory() on null object (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method setTargetDirectory() on null object
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at grails.ui.console.GrailsSwingConsole.runInstance(GrailsSwingConsole.groovy:61)
    at grails.ui.console.GrailsSwingConsole.main(GrailsSwingConsole.groovy:39)
| Error Fatal error during compilation java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method setTargetDirectory() on null object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10768 which is fixed in 2.3.3. That should be released this week, hopefully on Wednesday the 20th.

Answer (score 2):

For those who can't upgrade to 2.3.x line quite yet, the issue can be worked around by deleting `(user_home)/.grails/2.2.x/projects/(your project)` and re-running any grails command.